# prioritize wifi over bridge connection

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, lan, bridge

i have 2 internet connection in my home one is Ethernet and the other one is WiFi and they are different internet connection with different ISPs. i usually connect both connection to my laptop so whenever i need Ethernet i turn off WiFi and whenever i need WiFi i turn it on and connect it. i usually use my WiFi connection but my Ethernet is with bridge connection so modem is in bridge mode and i connect with my connection on windows so i wanted to know is there a way to prioritize WiFi over bridge connection or not?
let me say it in another way!
we all know we can have 2 internet connection at the same time in laptop 1 through WiFi and the other through LAN. when we connect both Lan and WiFi at the same time windows will automatically choose one of the internet connection and use it as main internet for system and the other connection will not be used.by default windows usually use ethernet as main connection through internet and will not use WiFi as long as ethernet is connected. we can change this default in windows to use WiFi over Lan and for doing so we have to set interface metrics in IPV4 settings(which you all know that). when we set interface metrics then windows will use wifi as main connection and will not use Lan as long as WiFi is connected.(just like this picture where i connect both lan and wifi and internet icon is WiFi which means it uses WiFi over Lan https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CU8eetO3e8rIwICT0EmiXsBtxxQJ-c0t/view)
so far so good!
but my lan connection is a little different to others! most people usually setup their lan modem to be PPPOE/PPPOA protocol but for some reason i setup my modem to use Bridge protocol (more info: https://whirlpool.net.au/wiki/modem_to_router_bridging_guide)
whenever a user use bridge protocol he has to set a broadband connection from windows setting and connect that broadband connection(in dial up section of windows setting) to access the internet (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YS1YRLOeCz4eo_8yZb3vS2mWQyLt6ybK/view) so if you only plug in lan you will get no internet in bridge mode.
now my problem is that whenever i connect my broadband connection i gain access to internet and it's ok but windows will automatically use my Lan connection instead of WiFi which exactly opposite of what i want! i want windows to use WiFi over lan but because my lan connection is with a broadband, windows will choose ethernet no matter what!(look at my internet icon in this picture and you see it's Lan icon which means windows is using Lan connection https://drive.google.com/file/d/13F2kdNz9XnIQbbUOOHrH91Y0zjbQ6Ejx/view)
i wanted to know that is there any way i could do to force windows to use WiFi over Lan?

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you bridged why you need the bridge? If you would just setup two default routes one over WLAN the other over LAN, everything would work.

Comment: yeah i could manage that by setting up 2 default route and i did it before and it was ok but for some reason i have to connect to my LAN internet with bridge protocol so i have to plug in LAN and connect broadband connection. with Lan plugged in and no broadband connection my internet will not work because i set modem to work on bridge protocol(and i don't want to change protocol to pppoe)

Comment: sorry, your description is very hard to understand, a diagram (physical and logical) would be helpful

Comment: sry for bad description
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CU8eetO3e8rIwICT0EmiXsBtxxQJ-c0t/view?usp=sharing
see above photo, you can see i have 2 network connection one is ethernet 3(which is my lan) one is Irancell which is my WiFi. right now on ethernet 3 is said no internet connection because i setup my modem with bridge protocol. people usually set their modem on PPPOE connection in which they will give ISP username and password to modem and modem connect automatically. but i didn't pick PPPOE i picked bridge on modem so when i set modem to bridge mode i have to connect to ISP manually.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uQjw5rtUbGT1wMRTd8bWTWSUmEzqnTkI/view?usp=sharing
now in this picture you see i created a broadband connection. to connect to internet with my lan i have to connect broadband connection otherwise i'll get no internet.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YS1YRLOeCz4eo_8yZb3vS2mWQyLt6ybK/view?usp=sharing
now that broadband connection connected i can use internet from LAN.
now see this:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/13F2kdNz9XnIQbbUOOHrH91Y0zjbQ6Ejx/view?usp=sharing
you see there is 3 connection 2 were before and 1 connection added which is broadband.

Comment: now at first picture i put before you saw 2 connection at same time but windows use wifi instead of lan because i set interface metrics in IPV4 settings
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VSf4uSrJZLiuN0RzYPTE2DMF5uFo9WEy/view?usp=sharing
see this i set wifi to priority 1 and Ethernet to 2 this metrics will cause windows to use wifi instead of LAN when both are connected. but metrics won't work when i connect broadband. as last picture i put in previous comment you can see internet icon turned into lan icon instead of wifi and windows now use lan even that i set metrics, windows still use lan!

Comment: i hope with these comments i could clarify for you still sry if it's not a good explaining

Comment: Please add this to your question, it's too confusing just in the comments